# Transforming OCaml code to F#

Tags: f#, ocaml

I'm transforming some OCaml code to F# having a problem with the OCaml `let...and...` which only exists in F# by using a recursive function. 
I have the given OCaml code:

```
let matches s = let chars = explode s in fun c -> mem c chars
let space = matches " \t\n\r"
and punctuiation = matches "() [] {},"
and symbolic = matches "~'!@#$%^&*-+=|\\:;<>.?/"
and numeric = matches "0123456789"
and alphanumeric = matches "abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz_'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

which I want to use in these two methods:

```
let rec lexwhile prop inp = match inp with
c::cs when prop c -> let tok,rest = lexwhile prop cs in c+tok,rest
|_->"",inp

let rec lex inp = 
match snd(lexwhile space inp)with
[]->[]
|c::cs ->let prop = if alphanumeric(c) then alphanumeric
                    else if symbolic(c) then symbolic
                    else fun c ->false in
                    let toktl,rest = lexwhile prop cs in
                    (c+toktl)::lex rest
```

Has someone any idea how I have to change it that so that I can use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to translate "[Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/atp/index.html)".

Did you see: [An F# version of the book code](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/) is now available! Thanks to Eric Taucher, Jack Pappas and Anh-Dung Phan.

You need to look at [intro.fs](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/blob/master/FSharpx.Books.AutomatedReasoning/intro.fs)

```ml
// pg. 17 
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------- // 
// Lexical analysis.                                                         // 
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------- // 


let matches s =  
    let chars =  
        explode s  
    fun c -> mem c chars 

let space = matches " \t\n\r"  

let punctuation = matches "()[]{}," 

let symbolic = matches "~`!@#$%^&*-+=|\\:;<>.?/" 

let numeric = matches "0123456789" 

let alphanumeric = matches "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789" 

let rec lexwhile prop inp = 
    match inp with 
    | c :: cs when prop c -> 
        let tok, rest = lexwhile prop cs 
        c + tok, rest 
    | _ -> "", inp 

let rec lex inp = 
    match snd <| lexwhile space inp with 
    | [] -> [] 
    | c :: cs -> 
        let prop = 
            if alphanumeric c then alphanumeric 
            else if symbolic c then symbolic 
            else fun c -> false 
        let toktl, rest = lexwhile prop cs 
        (c + toktl) :: lex rest
```

I asked many [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243762/guy-coder?tab=questions) here while working on the translation and prefixed them with `Converting OCaml to F#:`. If you look in the comments you will see how the three of us came to work on this project.

Comment: Wow you are making it easy for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you trying to use the book or just needed that piece of code?

Comment: I'm trying to use the book and to translate it. That was just a problem where I did not find a solution. @Guy Coder

Comment: Since you are trying to use the book, take a look at all of the test cases and this [wiki page](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/wiki/Usage-Notes) and in particular [Seventy-Five Problems for Testing Automatic Theorem Provers](http://www.sfu.ca/~jeffpell/papers/75ATPproblems86.pdf)

Comment: Since you are also trying to translate the code, pay attention to initialization.fs, lib.fs and read the comments. The hardest part about translating the code is not the code but the differences in the environments. e.g OCaml has a preprocessor and F# doesn't, etc.

Comment: If you are trying to understand the basics of the code check out the test code for [lib.fs](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/blob/master/FSharpx.Books.AutomatedReasoning.Tests/lib.fs), it is almost 9000 lines of low level test cases.

Comment: Also to see a run of all of the code under OCaml look at [OCaml Results.pdf](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/blob/master/OCaml%20Results.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

You can just write:

```
let explode s = [for c in s -> string c]
let matches str strc = 
    let eStr = explode str
    List.contains strc eStr 
let space = matches " \t\n\r"
let punctuation = matches "() [] {},"
let symbolic = matches "~'!@#$%^&*-+=|\\:;<>.?/"
let numeric = matches "0123456789"
let alphanumeric = matches "abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz_'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

F# tends to be written using lightweight, rather than verbose, syntax so you don't generally need to use the `in`, `begin` and `end` keywords.  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233199.aspx for details about the differences.

Personally, I would probably refactor all of those `string -> bool` functions into active patterns, e.g.:

```
let (|Alphanumeric|_|) str =
    match matches "abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz_'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" str with
    |true -> Some str
    |false -> None

let (|Symbolic|_|) str =
    match matches "~'!@#$%^&*-+=|\\:;<>.?/" str with
    |true -> Some str
    |false -> None
```

Then you can pattern match, e.g.:

```
match c with
|Alphanumeric _ -> // alphanumeric case
|Symbolic _ -> // symbolic case
|_ -> // other cases
```

Comment: Thanks, i used the keywords because they worked, but the Pattern Matching looks good.